# fct_relevel not working, change level order but not actual data

Tags: r, factors

I'm trying to manually order a variable and running into issues. I tried using `fct_relevel` in sevearl different ways, but that doesn't actually change the order of the variable "organism" in the dataset. When I check using `levels` the order is correct, but the actual data hasn't changed.

I also tried just `factor`, but that didn't work either.

I feel like it's an easy fix, but can't seem to figure it out. Would appreciate any help!

Here's the reprex:

```r
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    record_id = c(281L,94L,2L,
                  56L,133L,390L,272L,121L,279L,343L,314L,
                  324L,116L,225L,378L,72L,37L,254L,103L,249L,
                  319L,384L,47L,135L,39L,212L,35L,252L,1L,
                  112L,391L,88L,171L,283L,105L,131L,311L,
                  53L,150L,203L,220L,312L,4L,164L,385L,354L,
                  13L,266L,308L,111L),
    esbl_markers = c("CTX-M-27",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","VEB-6","CTX-M-15",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-27","CTX-M-27","CTX-M-15",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","VEB-6","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","SHV-2",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-3","CTX-M-27",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15, OXY-1-1","CTX-M-15",
                     "SHV-187, CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15",
                     "SHV-187","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","SHV-7","CTX-M-15",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-27","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-3",
                     "CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15","CTX-M-15"),
    organism = as.factor(c("Klebsiella pneumoniae",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli","Other",
                           "Klebsiella oxytoca",
                           "Escherichia coli","Klebsiella pneumoniae",
                           "Klebsiella pneumoniae","Klebsiella pneumoniae",
                           "Klebsiella pneumoniae",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli","Other",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli",
                           "Klebsiella pneumoniae","Other","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Other",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                           "Klebsiella pneumoniae","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Klebsiella pneumoniae",
                           "Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                           "Escherichia coli","Klebsiella pneumoniae",
                           "Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli","Other",
                           "Klebsiella pneumoniae",
                           "Escherichia coli","Klebsiella oxytoca",
                           "Klebsiella pneumoniae","Escherichia coli"))
)

clean_dat <- dat |> 
    mutate(organism = fct_relevel(organism, c("Escherichia coli", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Klebsiella oxytoca", "Other")))

clean_dat <- dat |>
    ungroup() |> 
    mutate(organism = fct_relevel(organism, "Klebsiella oxytoca", after = 2))

levels(clean_dat$organism)
#> [1] "Escherichia coli"      "Klebsiella pneumoniae" "Klebsiella oxytoca"   
#> [4] "Other"
head(clean_dat)
#>   record_id esbl_markers              organism
#> 1       281     CTX-M-27 Klebsiella pneumoniae
#> 2        94     CTX-M-15      Escherichia coli
#> 3         2     CTX-M-15      Escherichia coli
#> 4        56        VEB-6      Escherichia coli
#> 5       133     CTX-M-15      Escherichia coli
#> 6       390     CTX-M-15                 Other

clean_dat <- dat |> 
    mutate(organism = factor(organism, levels = c("Escherichia coli", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Klebsiella oxytoca", "Other")))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] lubridate_1.9.2 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.0    
#>  [5] purrr_1.0.1     readr_2.1.4     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.0   
#>  [9] ggplot2_3.4.1   tidyverse_2.0.0
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_4.2.2   pillar_1.8.1     tools_4.2.2      digest_0.6.31   
#>  [5] timechange_0.2.0 evaluate_0.20    lifecycle_1.0.3  gtable_0.3.1    
#>  [9] pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.6      reprex_2.0.2     cli_3.6.0       
#> [13] rstudioapi_0.14  yaml_2.3.7       xfun_0.37        fastmap_1.1.1   
#> [17] withr_2.5.0      knitr_1.42       generics_0.1.3   fs_1.6.1        
#> [21] vctrs_0.5.2      hms_1.1.2        grid_4.2.2       tidyselect_1.2.0
#> [25] glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.4      rmarkdown_2.20  
#> [29] pacman_0.5.1     tzdb_0.3.0       magrittr_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2  
#> [33] scales_1.2.1     htmltools_0.5.4  colorspace_2.1-0 utf8_1.2.3      
#> [37] stringi_1.7.12   munsell_0.5.0
```

Comment: `fct_relevel` does not reorder your data. It's a convenience function to relevel a factor. If you want to change the order of your data, then you have to re-arrange your data using e.g. `dplyr::arrange`, e.g. `dplyr::arrange(organism)` to reorder by the re-leveled factor.

Comment: How do I use ```arrange``` when the order I want isn't alphabetical?

Comment: When you `arrange` by a factor the dataset is re-arranged by the order of the factor levels, i.e. after `fct_relevel`ing arrange will order according to the order of the levels.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you do not need to see the data in order, but you can do it with `clean_dat |> arrange(organism)` or `clean_dat |> arrange(desc(organism))`.